# Extending a home wireless network using two routers running tomato

Tags: wireless-networking, router, tomato

I have two **Asus RT-N16** routers each flashed with **Tomato** (actually Tomato USB).

UPSTAIRS:  **Router 'A'** (located upstairs) is connected to the internet via the WAN port and connected via a LAN port to a 10/100/1000 switch (Switch A).  Several desktops are also attached to Switch A.  Router A uses IP 192.168.1.**1**.

DOWNSTAIRS:  I've just acquired **Router 'B'** and set it to IP 192.168.1.**2**.  I have a cable running from Switch A downstairs to another switch (Switch B).  Tivo, a blu-ray player and a Mac are connected to Switch B.  My plan was to connect Router B to Switch B so that I have improved wireless access downstairs.  (The wireless signal from Router A gets weak downstairs in a number of locations.)

How should I configure Router B so that all devices in the house can see and talk to one another?  I know that I need to change DHCP on Router B so that it doesn't cover the same range as DHCP on Router A.  Should I be using WDS on the two routers, or is that unnecessary since I already have a wired connection between the two routers?  Any other thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks!  --Jeff

Comment: The answer from David is right, I just wanted to point out that if you already have a layer 2 connection between the two APs, then enabling WDS would add a second layer 2 connection and very likely cause a loop in your network, resulting in nothing but trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need WDS on the two routers. Set them to the same SSID and encryption mode but different channels (assuming you can spare the channel space). Disable the WAN on router B (you can bridge the WAN port to the LAN if you want so it's not wasted) and connect them LAN-to-LAN. Router B should have its DHCP server *disabled*.

Note that because the two access points are connected to each other through intermediary switches, you may have a "hiccup" when a device moves from one access point to the other (as the intermediary switches learn that the hardware address has moved). If this gets too annoying, and you don't move devices around too much, you can set them to different SSIDs and then manually choose which access point each device connects to.